# Enigmarch Day 4: Lock

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

<sub>This puzzle was created as part of [Enigmarch](https://enigmarch.com/), a daily puzzle construction challenge.</sub>

---

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "locks are keys" indeed--

> because these are the `CAPS Lock`, `NUM Lock`, and `SCROLL lock` keys on a keyboard!
>
>  The marked locations spell out the answer, **UNCLASP**.